# bindingsgenerator : warning bg8604

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have used visual studio2019, I have created an Android Binding library(Xamarin) solution and add my project aar file inside the Jars folder, then I clean & build the solution. Build successfully and generate a dll file, but I got some warnings about aar file classes,

```
1>"E:\xamarin apps\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" (Rebuild;BuiltProjectOutputGroup;BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DocumentationProjectOutputGroup;DocumentationProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroup;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SGenFilesOutputGroup;SGenFilesOutputGroupDependencies target) (1) ->
1>(GenerateBindings target) -> 
1>  BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8604: top ancestor LoginActivity not found for nested type Com.Aarproject.LoginActivity.1.
1>  BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8604: top ancestor SignupActivity not found for nested type Com.Aarproject.SignupActivity.1.
1>  BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8604: top ancestor SplashActivity not found for nested type Com.Aarproject.SplashActivity.1.
1>
1>
1>"E:\xamarin apps\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" (Rebuild;BuiltProjectOutputGroup;BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DocumentationProjectOutputGroup;DocumentationProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroup;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SGenFilesOutputGroup;SGenFilesOutputGroupDependencies target) (1) ->
1>(CoreCompile target) -> 
1>  E:\xamarin apps\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\obj\Release\generated\src\Com.Aarproject.BuildConfig.cs(44,59,44,67): warning CS0109: The member 'BuildConfig._members' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>  E:\xamarin apps\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\obj\Release\generated\src\Com.Aarproject.BuildConfig.cs(45,30,45,39): warning CS0109: The member 'BuildConfig.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>
1>    5 Warning(s)
1>    0 Error(s)
1>
```

Also, I have used the dll file in another Mobile Android App(Xamarin) under References, But I couldn't access my library classes( like LoginActivity, SplashActivity..)
   How can I access it, both a library and Android app solution have same target version 28.

Note: aar file project also that same version.

Comment: @UIaga,Can you provide your project at github and share the link here, I will try to test your project.